# when I try to run my existing flutter project in windows version, I am getting this error

Tags: windows, flutter, dart

[**I have an flutter project which I created long back when Flutter windows became stable version I want to use same project for windows version but it says this error.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBdCd.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to fix this error by downloading the [Nuget.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/install-nuget-client-tools) and adding it to your Windows' path manually.

The root problem may be related to your installation of Visual Studio [as described here](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows#windows-setup)

Comment: The root problem may be related to your installation of VSCode or Visual Studio?

Comment: Visual Studio. I edited my answer